# Convert from base 10 to base 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-systems

I understand the integer part, keep dividing by 5 and I get 112, but for the fraction part I need a help.

The number is:

$$
(32.\bar 5)_{10} = (112, ??)_{5}
$$
$$
0,5 * 5 = 2,5\\
0,5 * 5 = 2,5\\
0,5 * 5 = 2,5\\
0,5 * 5 = 2,5\\
$$
It's correct?
$$
(32.\bar 5)_{10} = (112,\bar2)_{5} ?
$$

Thanks.

Comment: In base $10$ we have $.5555...=\frac 59$.  Your repeating base 5 expression can be computed as $.222..=\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac {2}{5^n}=\frac 25\,\frac {1}{1-\frac 15}=\frac 24$, so they are not the same.   I did it hastily and got that $(.\bar 5)_{10}=(.\overline {234210})_5$.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @lulu The almighty [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%2F9+in+base+5) supports your claim.

Comment: @Arthur  So it does!  Phew.

Comment: To explain lulu's result $$\frac59*5=\frac{25}9=2\frac79\\
\frac79*5=\frac{35}9=3\frac89\\
\frac89*5=\frac{40}9=4\frac49\\
\frac49*5=\frac{20}9=2\frac29\\
\frac29*5=\frac{10}9=1\frac19\\
\frac19*5=\frac59=0\frac59$$ and repeat

Comment: @emecarv I think our fault (mine and yours) is to ignore  the _bar_! I mean $(.\bar 5)_{10} \ne (.5)_{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seems sensible. Recurring decimals (or quinaries?) are not a feature of the base. Compare this number in ternary, which is 1012.12 exactly. Can you convert to nonary (base 9)?

See e.g. http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/Num/frac.htm

Comment: Yes, but the period may differ depending on the base. So assuming the period should be one because it's one in decimal is wrong.